# How to fix the highlighter in the GridView that has some grouping rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am using a GridView that has many rows with the same values, so I grouped these rows using [GridViewHelper class][1]. Now I want to fix the highlighter since when it goes the first row, it highlights the first cell as shown in the snapshot below:
[image]

But if it goes to the second row, it doesn't highlight the first cell as shown in the snapshot below:
[image]

The css code for the highlighter is:

```
.grid .datatable .row:hover
{
    background-color:#fffacd;
    color:#000;
}
```

I used also the following JQuery and it did the same thing as CSS:

```
<!-- This Jquery is for highlighting any table, gridview and whatever -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("tr").filter(function() {
            return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
            }).css({ background: "ffffff" }).hover(
            function() { $(this).css({ background: "#C1DAD7" }); },
            function() { $(this).css({ background: "#ffffff" }); }
            );
            });
        </script>
        <!-- End -->
  [1]: http://www.agrine
```

i.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

It,s bovios because first cell belong to first row.Your first row has 5 cell but second has 4 cell.If you want highlight this style you should use `JavaScript` or `jQuery` or any other client side language.You should when mouse is over a row examine number of cells and then highlight them in apropriate way.

Comment: Thanks for you help but even with the JQuery I have the same issue.